# Trying to extract an MDI child window outside its MDI parent

Tags: winapi, mfc, mdi

I have been able to reparent an mdichild window to the desktop with the following code:

```
SetParent(hSeekedWindow,0);
SetWindowLong(hSeekedWindow,GWL_STYLE,WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CAPTION|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX|    WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_SIZEBOX);
SetWindowLong(hSeekedWindow,GWL_EXSTYLE,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE);
```

However, as soon as i try to resize the ex-childwindow the whole app crashes. I suppose this is because the exchild is not getting its messages anymore. My question is this: would i be able to make this work if i somehow created an invisible mdichild that forwards its messages to exchild?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's not healthy.  Do it the same way as Windows Forms does it, just re-create the window, now minus the WS_EX_MDICHILD style flag.  Destroy the old one.  Yes, you'll get a bit of flicker.  Leverage your existing code simply by giving this new window the same window procedure.